# Use WP_Query object inside a function

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I'm developing a responsive WordPress theme and instead of using frameworks, I've created one my own.

I'm trying NOT to repeat myself (meaning, I don't want to write extra markup all the time), so I'm generating the HTML that comes before the `.grid-unit div` element with a `fluid_grid` PHP function that takes a function as a first parameter.

I'm pulling some custom post types using `WP_Query`:

```
function slider_template() {
    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'slides',
        'posts_per_page' => 10
    );     
    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );    
    // Check if the Query returns any posts
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {    
        // I'm passing an anonymous function here, that needs to be called later on
        fluid_grid( function() {
            ?>    
            // Here goes the markup that should be printed out later   
            <?php
        } ); // Close the anonymous function, and end the fluid_grid function.
    } // End of the if statement
} // End of slider_template function
```

After visiting the page, I'm getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on null in ...`

I've tried making the `$the_query` global, but ended up with the same result (`$the_query` is still null).

Is it possible to get `$the_query` variable working inside the anonymous function? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic PHP. Just a note before I continue, never ever globalize variables. Wordpress has already done quite a crappy job regarding this. Globalization is evil, because anyone and anything, knowingly or unknowingly can change a global variable. This makes globals a nightmare to debug. So in short, **NEVER EVER** globalize.

Whenever you need to pass something outside a anonymous function to the function, you should use the `use()` keyword. As example, you can try

```
function () use( $the_query )
{
    var_dump( $the_query );
}
```

### EDIT:

In your code, you can do the following

```
fluid_grid( function() use ( $the_query )
{
    ?>    
    // Here goes the markup that should be printed out later   
    <?php
} );
```

Comment: *"NEVER EVER globalize"* - specially those *big corporate capitalist* variables ;-) (looks like it's Friday again in the comments ;-)

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!  
Before I add this comment, I want to note something:  
- To all of you who encounter the same problem, I've also found an alternative by instead of using an anonymous function, I used a closure(which is a non-anonymous function), where I put the `$the_query` variable as a parameter.  
But, thanks to @Pieter , everything is now much more simplified and we can go the short way.

Comment: @birgire Friday for sure it is, and a very important weekend, my team, LIONS, are playing final tommorow, so to kick it of, here is my favorite team song, [Bring it on, by my friend Gert Koevert](https://af-za.facebook.com/gertkoevert/posts/882944488415535).

Comment: @WildChild glad my 2 cents helped you out. It was my pleasure helping, enjoy ;-)

Comment: awesome, best of luck ;-) @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `fluid_grid`, but this looks like a scope issue. You are creating an anonymous function inside your call:

```
fluid_grid(function() {

});
```

This function does not have access to `$the_query`. You need to see if you can pass the query var to the function, or try globalizing it.

```
fluid_grid(function() {
   global $the_query;
   //do stuff 
});
```

Comment: Globalizing variables is just bad practice, and even more so with easy to reproduce variables like `$the_query`

Comment: In general, yes, when trying to knock out some Wordpress code with PHP, in a scenario like above, is hardly a big deal.